# Populate all fields in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there a way to populate ***all*** fields when running a mongoose query, in case you don't know in advance which fields are the referenced documents? Something like this:

```
schema = new Schema({ ref: {type:ObjectId, ref:'ref'}});
db = Model('data', schema);

db.find({}).populate('*').
// or
db.find({}).populate({path:'*'}).

//=> {ref: {_id:...,}} // "ref" is populated automatically
```

Comment: you ca do that if you use, `mongoose-autopopulate`, only if you have access to the schema.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately for me though, it only works if and only for those fields to which you add `autopopulate:true` in the schema. But looking at it's code, I think I might be able to create a similar plugin that truly does auto-populate all fields

Comment: This seems like a very questionable thing to want to do. Population is expensive and should only be done as needed.

Answer (score 6):

I wrote a small plugin. It goes through the schema and looks for fields with a `ref` property and adds them as a path which is fed to `.populate()` in a pre-find hook. Tested with Mongoose v4

```
function autoPopulateAllFields(schema) {
    var paths = '';
    schema.eachPath(function process(pathname, schemaType) {
        if (pathname=='_id') return;
        if (schemaType.options.ref)
            paths += ' ' + pathname;
    });

    schema.pre('find', handler);
    schema.pre('findOne', handler);

    function handler(next) {
        this.populate(paths);
        next();
    }
};
module.exports = autoPopulateAllFields;
```

```
var articleSchema = new Schema({
    text: {type: 'String'},
    author: {type: 'ObjectId', ref: 'user'}
});
articleSchema.plugin(autoPopulateAllFields);
var Article = mongoose.model('article', articleSchema);
```

```
Article.find({}) => [ {text:..., author: { _id:..., name:... /*auto-populated*/} } ]
```

Comment: why not a method? bad practice always populate all.

Comment: For my mongoose version I had to modify like if ((schemaType.options || schemaType.caster.options).ref) .. and I had to call populate() per path name, however its a workable solution thanks. And Ninja its not a 'practice' its an option, I cant believe you wasted keystrokes on ur comments you must have been bored.

Comment: Will that include paths with array of refs?

Comment: The `if` should be like that: `!(type?.caster?.options || type.options).ref`

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to export a variable somewhere that contains the list of all populated fields like :

```
export const POPULATED_FIELDS = ['filed1','field2']
```

then when you want to populate the fields just wrtie

```
Model.findById('some_id').populate(POPULATED_FIELDS)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, for each Model I also have a Class, and inside that Class I include some methods which returns the relevant information required for each case. This allow me to create custom lists of 'filtered' fields per class, used on query options for:
what to return on GET routes, what is allowed to modify on PUT routes, and which fields to populate... etc.

When need to add or remove any 'allowed' field just do it on the class method, not all over the rest of the code.

example:

```
// all imports done

class Users {
  // Query parameters
  sortBy() { return 'name'; } 
  getAllFieldsFilter() { return 'name email membertype created_at updated_at'; }
  getAllPopulateIndexed() { return { path: 'membertype', select: 'name canpost' };}
  
  // other methods...
  constructor() {}
}
module.exports = {
  Users,
};
```

Later it can be used on the queries, for example:

```
User.find(queryOptions, Users.getAllFieldsFilter())
  .sort(Users.sortBy())
  .populate(Users.getAllPopulateIndexed());
```